# A flutter code snippet is showing an error code of receiver can't be null

Tags: flutter

The following code snippet is showing an error code. I have tried a few things but unable to get a solution. Can anyone please suggest a resolution for this.

> The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.

````
  if (!totalAmounts.containsKey(dataPoint.month)) {
    totalAmounts[dataPoint.month] = 0;
  }
  totalAmounts[dataPoint.month] ??= 0; // Initialize to 0 if null
  totalAmounts[dataPoint.month] += dataPoint.amount ?? 0; // Add 0 if amount is null
} ```
````

Comment: The compiler doesn't know the *semantics* of `Map.operator[]`; it doesn"t know if it's guaranteed to be initialized.  It only knows that it's declared to return a nullable type and therefore might return `null`.  I'd just combine the two lines to `totalAmounts[dataPoint.month] = (totalAmounts[dataPoint.month] ?? 0) + (dataPoint.amount ?? 0)`.

Comment: since you can keep it 0 why don't you remove null and keep 0. Else you can create temporary variable(type `int` not `int?`) that holds the initialisation and assignment. Then assign it to `totalAmounts[dataPoint.month]`.